# Shiny dynamic layout: Automatically wrap fixed width elements to the next row

Tags: r, layout, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm aware of `fluidPage()` and `fixedPage()` layouts for shiny. In my case though it would be nice to have another behaviour for elements (plots/input fields/shinydashboard boxes).

Elements should have a fixed width (and height) and move automatically to the next row if the display width changes.

Legend:

```
[...] <- Element
| <- Right browser window border
```

Examples:

```
1. Big screen case
[...] [..] [.....] [...] [...]        |

2. Small screen case
[...] [..] [.....] [...] |
[...]                    |

3. Even smaller screen case
[...] [..]  |
[.....]     |
[...] [...] |
```

Is a layout like this possible with shiny/shinydashboard?

Comment: I think `flowLayout` might be what you're looking for. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/flowLayout.html.

Comment: That seems to be what I'm searching for. Thanks! If you post an answer I'll accept it. As an additional question: Do you have an idea if and how I could use shinydashboard boxes within this layout? They require a width value in the bootstrap system and that does not seem compatible with `flowLayout()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SimonLarsen I was able to find a solution. Shiny offers `flowLayout()` which supports this kind of layout. Unfortunately shinydashboard boxes can't be used within this framework, because they expect width values within the bootstrap grid framework. You would have to change the implementation of `shinydashbaord::box()` to work with pixel width values and that would cause all sorts of other problems down the line.

I've opted for the following solution:

```
shiny::fluidRow(
  shinydashboard::box(
    width = 12,
    shiny::div(
      style = "overflow-x: scroll",
      shiny::flowLayout(
        cellArgs = list(
          style = "
          min-width: 300px; 
          width: auto; 
          height: auto; 
          border: 1px solid darkgray; 
          padding: 10px;
          margin: 10px;
        "),
        plotly::plotlyOutput(
          width = "500px",
          ns("plot1")
        ),
        plotly::plotlyOutput(
          width = "500px",
          ns("plot1")
        ),
        plotly::plotlyOutput(
          width = "1045px",
          ns("plot2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I build my own boxes with fixed height and for each plot/content element an individually defined width.